# Post status update to Page Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I'am really new to all this Facebook development, and I wanted to integrate Facebook within my personal website.
I am now trying to test if what I want is possible.

**I want to post a status from my server, via php/js to my Page in Facebook.
How can I do so?**

B.W.
I saw that there is this FBJS function called "Facebook.streamPublish"
But I don't know how to integrate it.
Is there any possible way to do so?
Can you give me an example?

-Secondly, what is an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an access_token after facebook authenticates you. You will need this access_token for all subsequent API calls. You can find the details here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

You can use graph API for publishing on the wall and doing other allowed actions. Details of publishing api can be found here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

But do have a look on the facebook policy, because publishing automatically to a wall is considered violation.
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: But I think I need an app for that process,
I asked how to post via php/js to my >Page Wall<,
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Read the documentation. It has php examples. What I am not sure of whether posting automatically on the wall is a policy violation. Facebook policy document suggests that post on wall only on explicit user action.

Comment: hmmm...
I can't find any example that does that.
Can you send me the example's link?

Comment: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ shows how to get started and fire a graph api call. The graph api call that you need is at the bottom of the page I have shared above. Use them as described to get the required result.